# How can I read a data from OMNIKEY 3121 smart card device?

Tags: c++, omnikey

I have a software written by c++, the functionality of this software is to connect to OMNIKEY smart card, and read/write some data, I'm using a following code for read:

```
m_Errorcode = SCard3WBPReadData(m_Handle, length, m_Data, m_ulOffset);
```

This was right an no problem there, but after the OmniKey company changed the chip from x-chip to AVIATOR under new product (HID Global OMNIKEY Smart Card Reader), my code stopped and failed to read a data by preceding code.
I have read a lot and I think the problem can be solved by changing a voltage sequence as described at (page 13) in developer guide
https://www.hidglobal.com/doclib/files/resource_files/plt-03635_a.0_-_synchronous-api_software_developer_guide.pdf

There is also chapter in OK SW Dev Guide (Page 17) which suggesting an hexa value (0x1B) to make this change
https://www.hidglobal.com/sites/default/files/resource_files/plt-03099_a.3_-_omnikey_sw_dev_guide.pdf

but until now I can't obtain which is a suitable API function that I must use to pass this suggested Hexa  value.